# cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>' when convering from df.append to pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a little parser that is gathering RSS feed channel to pandas df. Everything works as expected but I get this waring

```
The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead
```

After some research, I converted my dicts to list and then started to concatenate but now I get the

```
type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

how to rewrite my for loop to get expected result

**working code with warning**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['title', 'link'])

with response as r:
    items = r.html.find('item', first=False)
    
    for item in items:

        title = item.find('title', first=True).text
        link = item.find('guid', first=True).text
        
        row = {'title': title, 'link': link}
        df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

**slightly modified, gives error**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['title', 'link'])
tmp = []
with response as r:
    items = r.html.find('item', first=False)
    
    for item in items:
        title = item.find('title', first=True).text
        link = item.find('guid', first=True).text
        row = [title, link]
        tmp.append(row)

    df = pd.concat(tmp)
```

Comment: Which line of code gives you this error?

Comment: las one: df = pd.concat(tmp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.concat` works to concatenate two or more pandas objects.
If you have succesfully constructed a list of dicts containing your data *(which you have in the `tmp` variable)* then you can transform it into a dataframe just by using the default `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['title', 'link'])
tmp = []
with response as r:
    items = r.html.find('item', first=False)
    
    for item in items:
        title = item.find('title', first=True).text
        link = item.find('guid', first=True).text
        row = {'title': title, 'link': link}
        tmp.append(row)

    df = pd.DataFrame(tmp)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pd.concat() for dataframes. You just need the create your dataframe with the tmp list. Maybe you can get data with pd.read_html I don't know actually.

```
    tmp = []
    with response as r:
        items = r.html.find('item', first=False)
        
        for item in items:
            title = item.find('title', first=True).text
            link = item.find('guid', first=True).text
            row = [title, link]
            tmp.append(row)
    df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=['title', 'link'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `row` to dict, e.g.:

```
row = {'col1': [title], 'col2': [link]}
```

and the append line to:

```
tmp = tmp.append(pd.DataFrame(row))
```

don't forget to reset the tmp to dataframe:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame()
```